# Cloud function exception in Flutter

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm facing an issue after updating all my libraries to comply with AndroidX.
Specifically, when I try to use the package "cloud_functions", I receive this error message:

```
flutter: throwing generic exception
flutter: Exception: Unable to call function funName
```

Now, I didn't touch the code handling the call, I simply updated the packages in the yaml file.

My code is:

```
cfResponse = await CloudFunctions.instance.call(
      functionName: 'funName',
      parameters: {
        "p1": p1,
        "p2": p2,
      },
    ).then((response) {
      return response;
    }).catchError((error) {
      print(error);
      return null;
    });
```

I'm having the same issue both on Android and iOS.

My libraries are at version:
- cloud_functions: ^0.1.1
- firebase_auth: ^0.8.1+4

I'm on Flutter 1.2.1 and Dart 2.1.2

Comment: Hey, AndroidX compatibility can bring up quite some problems with your packages. One way to by-pass the feature is to avoid it alltogether and to use the latest release of each package before AndroidX. More info on that is [here.](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility#avoiding-androidx) Of course it's not a solution with the future in mind, but it might help you for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same issue but only on iOS and came across [cloud_functions bug](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/1301). I manually set the region like the PR does and was able to get it to work. It looks like the fix will be in a coming release.